# Динамическое размещение текста в тег в HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Как динамически после клика на кнопку разместить определенный текст на странице в браузере, чтобы потом опять можно кликнуть на кнопку, и текст добавился к предыдущему и т д после клика кнопок ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('span').text($('span').text() + 'Some text >>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<span>Add text here >></span>
```

Comment: Огромное огромное спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

Что-то мне это напоминает...

#### html

```
<div class="viewport"></div>
<button class="add-text-button">Add text</button>
```

#### js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

  var text = "произвольный текст\n";

  var viewport = document.querySelector(".viewport");
  var button = document.querySelector('.add-text-button');

  button.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    viewport.innerText += text;
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#txt").append("<p>Hello</p>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="txt">
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" />
```